# How do I add new Video entirely from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to add a new VideoJS object and set it up entirely from JS, without having a DOM video element.
The result is that the video is loaded but there aren't any VideoJS controls.
Here is the code:

```
obj = document.createElement('video');
                $(obj).attr('id', 'example_video_1');
                $(obj).attr('class', 'video-js vjs-default-skin');

                var source = document.createElement('source');
                $(source).attr('src', path);
                $(source).attr('type', 'video/mp4');
                $(obj).append(source);

                $("#content").append(obj);
                _V_("example_video_1", {}, function () {
                    //
                    }
                });
```

I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay took a look at video-js, it's quite nice. Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"> </div>
      <!-- appending video here -->
    <hr />
    <!-- written in html -->
    <video id="example_video_by_hand" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg" preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
     <source type="video/mp4" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4">
   </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var obj,
    source;

obj = document.createElement('video');
$(obj).attr('id', 'example_video_test');
$(obj).attr('class', 'video-js vjs-default-skin');
$(obj).attr('width', '640');
$(obj).attr('data-height', '264');
$(obj).attr('controls', ' ');
$(obj).attr('poster', 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg');
$(obj).attr('preload', 'auto');
$(obj).attr('data-setup', '{}');

source = document.createElement('source');
$(source).attr('type', 'video/mp4');
$(source).attr('src', 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4');

$("#content").append(obj);
$(obj).append(source);
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/welcome/7929/edit) on jsbin.

---

**Updates:**

As [polarblau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564721/polarblau) pointed out in a comment the `jQuery.attr()` can take an object rather than having to call `jQuery.attr()` multiple times like in my first example.

*note:* The below is just an example and not a working demo.

```
 var attributes = {
   'id': 'example_video_test',
   'class': 'video-js vjs-default-skin',
   'width': '640',
   'data-height': '264',
   'controls': ' ',
   'poster': 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg',
   'preload': 'auto',
   'data-setup': '{}'
 }

 var element = $('<video/>').attr(attributes)
 //you would also have to add the source element etc but this gives
 //a good example of a shorter approach
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I see there is not need in the _V_ function like stated in VideoJS website.

Comment: OT: `.attr()` takes an object as well which lets you set all attributes nicely in one sitting. Also caching jQuery objects into variables is a good practice: `var $obj = $('<video/>').attr({…}) … `.

Comment: Just a note, you can also do a lot of the video setup in VJS as well (preference really). You can just set up a video with an id, then use Videojs to initialize the player with options and a new src.